# How to keep_window_open() not working depending on inputs

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I ran the following code twice.

Once when I input `Carlos 22`, the program ran correctly and `keep_window_open()` apparently worked as the console window stayed open, and displayed the `"Please enter a character to exit"` message.

**But when I input `22 Carlos` the program works as expected but the `keep_window_open()`does not work** - it simply closes as if I did not have that line in there at all.

*What is the reason for this behavior? And what is the best way I can keep the window open in all circumstances?*

***My code:***

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

// read name and age
int main()
{
    cout << "please enter your name and your age\n";
    string first_name =  "???";
    int age = -1;
    cin >> first_name >> age;
    cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";
    keep_window_open();
}
```

**The code and exercise are from Programming Principles and Practice Using C++.**

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the implementation of `keep_window_open()` doesn't ignore any characters already in the buffer.

from [Stroustrup's site](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h):

```
inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}
```

Here, `cin.clear()` will clear the error flag so that future IO operations will work as expected.  However, the failure you have (trying to input `Carlos` into an `int`) leaves the string `Carlos` in the buffer.  The read into `ch` then gets the `C` and the program exits.

You can use `cin.ignore()` to ignore characters in the buffer after this type of error.  You can see that `void keep_window_open(string s)` in the same file immediately below `void keep_window_open()` does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by invalid input to `cin`.

You can add error handling to avoid such issue by following:

change

```
cin >> first_name >> age;
cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";
```

to

```
cin >> first_name;
while (!(cin >> age)) {
  cout << "Invalid age, please re-enter.\n";
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```